# mysql query replacement to select all

Tags: php, mysql

> $sql  = "select a.time a.company a.deptime, a.destime, a.flight,
>   a.year, a.month, a.day, ".$ticket_to_heaven." as
>   ".$this->condition['type'].", ".$seat." as
>   ".$this->condition['type']."_s, a.company, a.time from
>   `".$this->TBLNAME."` a \n";

I would like to change it into 
$sql ="select * from ...."

But I am the 'a' sneaks in with error output. What a messy 'a'! could somebody please be of any help ? 
Thank you

[UPDATE]

I have changed it into something like this:

> $sql  = "select a.*, ".$ticket_to_heaven." as
>   ".$this->condition['type'].", ".$seat." as
>   ".$this->condition['type']."_s, a.company, a.time from
>   `".$this->TBLNAME."` a \n";

It still looks a little odd to me.

Comment: try select a.* from tablename a without a.anything,a.anythingelse

Comment: That is just an example, please reread my OP that there are php variables in use too.

Comment: You already have selected everything `*` from the table, there's no need for the other variables, they just get you the same values twice and add a security risk.

Answer (score 4):

use

```
select a.* from table a
```

or (without alias)

```
select * from table
```

Comment: You mean to leave the rest as it is after replacing all a.time, a.deptime etc with a.* only ? Thank you